# How to send a message from an Intent Service to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

Basically, i have an activity that has a progress dialog, i'm sending a message to an Intent to load all the data from the internet without any hiccup in the application. However, i was able to send a message to the service but i wasn't able to resend the message to the activity.
What to do?

Here's how i send message to the service:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    }
};
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, FillingDatabase.class);
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
intent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
startService(intent);
```

And here's how i recieve the message from the service:

```
messenger = (Messenger) intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
        message = Message.obtain(null, 1234);
            messenger.send(message);
```

But i wasnt able to know how to recieve that message in an activity, can someone explain the approach?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
    public void handleMessage(Message message) 
    {
       final Intent intent = new Intent(this, FillingDatabase.class);
       final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
       intent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
       startService(intent);
    };
};
```

Comment: @GrlsHu i recieved this error:
The local variable handler may not have been initialized

Comment: Make your `Handler` as `final` like `private final Handler handler = new Handler()`

Comment: @GrlsHu but you didn't answer my question, how can i recieve the message??

Answer (score 0):

use

handler.dispatchMessage();

and send an empty message.declare handler static and access it by class name or simply create object of class and then access it.

i think you can also use

handler.SendEmptyMessage();

Answer (score 0):

Here comes your exact solution,

Issue was already solved here  [sending message from IntentService to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830417/sending-message-from-intentservice-to-activity)

And for more better understanding about this, Here comes an working example where you can directly use it for implementation 
[Go here](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/)

Mark as OK if it works for you.