# update textview title in an Activity from a service

Tags: android, service, textview

i have an homeActivity which contains a webview with an actionbar, the title of the actionbar is an textview

```
public static TextView mTitleTextView;
```

and also has an class which do receive gcm message

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
```

after the app received a message i want to put the string to the textview of homeActivity, i tried to use

```
HomeActivity.mTitleTextView.setText("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");
```

but the app shutdown with error, i've read some old post and googled see something like broadcast receiver can solve this problem, but i not really understand how it works, can anyone show some actually source code which can be applied in my situation?

Comment: did u tried `HomeActivity h = new HomeActivity();` and `h.mTitleTextView.setText("9999999999");`  and don't forget to make `mTitleTextView` to `public`

Comment: But here when you want to update text when your `Home Activity in Forground`?

Comment: You can use LocalBroadcastManager here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service

Comment: @NealAhluvalia, you should newer create an instance of activity by yourself

Comment: Best way is do it using LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: @Yeah IO i read that post, but i don't have onCreate, i only have onHandleIntent, can i use LocalBroadcastManager in OnHandleIntent?

Comment: You can implement listener also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve by using handler,broadcat and Listener concept.But I think broadcast is easy to implement and understand but need to take care or register and unregister of broadcast.

**USING LISTENER**

Create a Listener class

```
public Interface Listener{
public void onResultReceived(String str);
}
```

Now implement it in activity like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements listener{
public void onResultReceived(String str){
mTitleTextView.setText(str)
 }
}
```

Initialize your  Listener by calling constructor of service from oncreate of Activity

```
new  GCMNotificationIntentService (MainActivity.this);
```

Now create public constructor of your service like below

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
public static Listener listener_obj;
public GCMNotificationIntentService (Listener listener)
{
listener_obj=listener;
}

Listener.onResultReceived("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999");
//send the data which should be shown on textview
```

**USING BROADCAST**

```
 registerReceiver( mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GETDATA"));
 //register localbraodcast with receiver object and intent filter inside oncreate
```

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         String str= intent.getStringExtra("DATA", "No Data");
         mTitleTextView.setText(str);
}

};
ondestroy()
{

 unregisterReceiver( mMessageReceiver);
}
```

Sending Data from service

```
Intent intent = new Intent("GETDATA");
intent.putExtra("DATA", "9999999");
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Comment: my IntentService class already has public GCMNotificationIntentService() { super("GcmIntentService"); }, i alter it into public GCMNotificationIntentService(Listener listener) { super("GcmIntentService"); listener_obj=listener;} , the app shutdown immediately when start

Comment: don't do that create another separate constructor and add it to service.Purpose of this constructor is only to initilaize listener nothing else

Comment: So, how can i initialize listener without using constructor?

Comment: but GCMNotificationIntentService not allow me to add  public IntentService (Listener listener)
 {
  listener_obj=listener;
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81244/discussion-between-shakeeb-ayaz-and-hkguile).

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler and send a message to parent activity from the `Intentservice`

**Parent Activity** :

Declaring Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle reply = msg.getData();
                // do whatever with the bundle here
            }
};
```

Invoking the intentservice:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentService1.class);
    intent.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(handler));
    startService(intent);
```

Inside IntentService:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    Messenger messenger = (Messenger) bundle.get("messenger");
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.setData(data); //put the data here
    try {
        messenger.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.i("error", "error");
    }
}
```

**or**

If you want to use the `BroadcastReceiver` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088315/start-intentservice-from-activity-and-refresh-activity-when-intentservice-is-fin) is good example for using that.

Comment: I think broadcast is easy to implement and understand but need to take care or register and unregister of broadcast..So better one should implement Handler .

Comment: Ya you are right  but if the service is running continuously in the background then broadcast receiver is a  better option

Comment: Hi kartheek I dont think that you can send messenger object in put extras ,it dose not support

Comment: You can send a Messenger through intent because it implements Parcelable. you can this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796612/how-to-send-a-message-from-an-intent-service-to-an-activity