# How to call a method in an Activity from another class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am working on an SMS application and I have a method in my `MainActivity` to perform a button click:

```
public void updateMessage() {
    ViewMessages.performClick();
}
```

This method works fine and performs the button click when I call this method from inside the `MainActivity` class.
But, when I call this method from any other class as shown below, where I call the Main Activity's `updateMessage` method from the `IntentServiceHandler` class, I am getting a `NullPointerException`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Button.performClick()' on a null object reference

```
public class IntentServiceHandler extends IntentService {

    public IntentServiceHandler() {
       super("IntentServiceHandler");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        TransactionDataBase transactionDB = new TransactionDataBase(this, 1);
        transactionDB.addMessage(message);
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.updateMessage();
    }
}
```

How can I handle this?

Edit: I even tried to make the updateMessage method static, and now i get the following exception

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Never ever `new` an Activity. That's your first problem. Your Activity probably needs to bind to that service and handle the message

Comment: update the question. i made it static, and now i am getting a different exception

Comment: `static` isn't the proper solution. Thats just a terrible workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending message from IntentService to Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830417/sending-message-from-intentservice-to-activity) or [Intent from Service to Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997463/send-intent-from-service-to-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the method of Activity in an IntentService, try to use Intent to communicate between Activity and IntentService.

1. Replace the last two statements onHandleIntent() with

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   broadcastIntent.setAction(MainActivity.UPDATE_MESSAGE);
   broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
2. And you should register a BroadcastReceiver in onCreate() of MainAcitivty like

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       // ....

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction(UPDATE_MESSAGE);

       receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override 
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // do something based on the intent's action 
           // for example, call updateMessage()
           } 
       };

       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
   }
   ```
3. onHandleIntent of IntentService run in another thread (instead of main thread / ui thread), so Updating UI components in onHandleIntent isn't permitted.